# Where does the iris go when it is open?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

What space do the pieces of the gate iris go into?   There is nothing to be seen when the iris is in the open position.

Was this ever explained or depicted?   Or it is just out-of-universe limitations of CGI early in the series that they just gloss over forever?

Comment: I'm sure someone can post some screen captures...

Comment: @Himarm:    Geometrically, it can't fold down to a shape like that.   Possibly at all, and definitely without thousands of pieces.   It's not depicted that way.

Comment: It appears to work the same way as the iris of a lens.

Comment: It's all pretty well explained http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_technology_in_Stargate#Iris

Comment: It's stored in the Stargate's bag of holding.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - why do you think it's geometrically impossible? As shown in the animated gif in the wiki article, you can still see a circular band of metal when the iris is open, so if each of the individual blades is no wider than than that band, it doesn't seem geometrically impossible that they could fold in that way by rotating their long axis from a radial direction to a tangential one.

Comment: @Hypnosifl  The width of the "blades" (radially) is wider than the width of the "band" (axially).   Even on the small animated GIFs you can see that.

Comment: @ThePopMachine - yes, looking at it again it seems you're right.

Comment: It would require a close-up shot to confirm, but as I recall there is a gap on the inside of the ring which the metal could conceivably slide into.

Comment: @calccrypto:  possible duplicate?   That is a duplicate.   Agreed.